# Selenium webdriver timeouts don't set when usingServer

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try a lot to set Timeout but it still uses the 300-second default timeout

```
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver');

let driver = await new Builder()
     .forBrowser('firefox')
     .usingServer('http://selenium-server:4000/wd/hub')
     .build();
const capabilities = await driver.getCapabilities();
capabilities['map_'].set('timeouts', { implicit: 0, pageLoad: 60000, script: 30000 });
await driver.get(url);
```

I also try `driver.manage().timeouts()` but got error: `driver.manage(...).timeouts is not a function`

`"selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no stable version of selenium 4. At least I tried `4.0.0-alpha-6` and this version has a lot of problems.

Let's try [`3.6.0`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver/v/3.6.0) instead.

Then this worked:
`driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60000);`